# Showing that $f$ must be continuous

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function at $a$ interior point of $I$. Suppose that there exists $L\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim \frac{f(y_{n})-f(x_{n})}{y_{n}-x_{n}} = L$ for all sequences $(x_{n}),(y_{n})\in I$ such that $x_{n}<a<y_{n}$. Then, $f'(a)$ exists and it is equal to $L$.

Show that f must be continuous at $a$ to this theorem holds.

I don't know how to construct a counter-example when $f$ is not continuous at $a$.

Comment: Well have you tried any simple examples of discontinuous functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a counterexample, let
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x=a$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$

Then the limit exists and is equal to 0, but $f$ is not continuous (hence not even differentiable).

Comment: Thank you, Hugo!